# Hide keyboard when a specific number of digit has entered on editText

Tags: android-studio

Goal: 
When ever 6 digit entered on ID_Display, It would hide the keyboard.

Problem:
Keyboard wouldnt hide unless Keyboard "Enter" is press

```
 public void keyboard_hide_Listener() {
    ID_Display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ID_display);
    if (ID_Display != null) {ID_Display.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event != null && (ID_Display.getText().length()>=6)) { //event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    System.out.println("Edit Text Length: " +ID_Display.getText().length());
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ID_Display.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                    return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(ID_Display.getText().length()>=6`

You should probably go with `v.GetText()` instead of `ID_display`

Comment: Changed it to 
"if ((event != null) && (v.getText().length() >= 6)) { //event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)"

but I still get the same result